# cv:OutOfMemoryError Java IplImage

Tags: java, opencv, memory, javacv, iplimage

I have been writing a motion detection program and have currently got an error (memory insufficient).

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 836352 bytes) in cv::OutOfMemoryError, file ........\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52
java.lang.RuntimeException: ........\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:52: error: (-4) Failed to allocate 836352 bytes in function cv::OutOfMemoryError

```
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvCreateImage(Native Method)
at cv.MotionDetectionUtil.resizeIplImage(MotionDetectionUtil.java:170)
at cv.MotionDetectionUtil.grabFrame(MotionDetectionUtil.java:87)
at applet.Panel$2.run(Panel.java:153)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Above is the error I'm getting. They are referring to the following locations.

Firstly this one. Referring to the createImage line.

```
 private IplImage resizeIplImage(IplImage img, double percent) {
    double width = ((double) img.width() * percent) / 100;
    double height = ((double) img.height() * percent) / 100;

    IplImage dest_img;

    dest_img = opencv_core.cvCreateImage(
            opencv_core.cvSize((int) width, (int) height), img.depth(),
            img.nChannels());

    //resize the image
    opencv_imgproc.cvResize(img, dest_img, opencv_imgproc.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

    return dest_img;
}
```

Then the second line of this:

```
 if (REDUCE_TO_PERCENT > 0 && REDUCE_TO_PERCENT != 100) {
        lastImage = resizeIplImage(img, REDUCE_TO_PERCENT);
    } else {
        lastImage = img;
    }
```

Finally the first line of this...

```
//update the image
                    img = detector.grabFrame(brightness, contrast);
                    image = img;
                    CameraPanel.updateImage(image);
```

I can't fix this for the life of me, can anyone tell me (in detail) what I am doing wrong? (ideally with an example of some sort). I'm new to java (especially opencv etc).

Thanks.

Comment: How big is the original image in memory? H * W * BitsPerPixel?

Comment: Not sure how to check? But it is from my ip camera, reading the image in using RTSP then resizing to fit to screen.

Comment: If you can write the file out to disk, Windows explorer can tell you the h * w by just mousing over the image. How many times do you call resizeIplImage()? Is it called in a loop? It wouldn't surprise me that you're running out of memory if you're grabbing frames from a video and then trying to resize them. Everything will need to be uncompressed all at once. And if you're running it in real time, you would probably run out of memory very quickly.

Comment: It is called in a loop, it resizes each frame before putting it onto my Jframe.. If you look at the second block of code, it basically calls that function to resize the image for every frame.

Comment: You'll run out of memory quickly. Why not just display it full-size but resize the container that it's displaying in? I'm not sure what package you're using but you're decompressing the video and creating a separate image for each frame. That's not efficient.